# Copy Delta Table from ADLS to Snowflake causing issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to copy delta table from datalake to snowflake.
causing some issues.

1. showing below error

---

ErrorCode=SnowflakeUnsupportedCouldPlatformForImport,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Snowflake only support the account hosted in azure platform while as sink connector, please make sure your account is hosted in azure, current region and platform is 'AWS_US_EAST_1',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

---

Is it needed to have snowflake should be Azure region (snowflake) to copy data or AWS region (snowflake) can also copy data from Datafactory.

Please let me know.
Thanks

Shanucnu

Answer (score 0):

> Snowflake only support the account hosted in azure platform while as sink connector, please make sure your account is hosted in azure, current region and platform is 'AWS_US_EAST_1

***The sink connector in use only supports Snowflake accounts hosted on Azure.*** your Snowflake account is currently hosted on the AWS cloud platform, and unfortunately, ***Azure Data Factory (ADF) doesn't provide support for this specific sink configuration.***

The workaround for this issue is given by @sachin.mittal [here](https://cloudyard.in/2023/07/odbc-connector-with-azure-ir-contd/) is **to connect the snowflake database with ODBC driver and then transfer the data to it.**

- Install Snowflake ODBC driver on machine from [here](https://developers.snowflake.com/odbc/) and configure it with below settings:

> Open ODBC data sources (64-bit) >> System DSN >> click on Add to create a new data source >> select **SnowFlakeDSIIDriver** >> and fill your server details

[image]

- Then create a self-hosted Integration runtime with similar name of **Data Source** created in ODBC driver.
- Then create linked service for this ODBC driver and transfer your data to SnowFlake account hosted in AWS region.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Do we have any other approach other than ODBC driver approach.

Comment: currently we have only this approach for Snowflake other than azure region.